# Gradient behavior in pytorch with multi-layer loss

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a loss where each layer plays into the loss. Which is the correct approach in terms of making sure the weights are updated properly?

```
# option 1
x2 = self.layer1(x1)
x3 = self.layer2(x2)
x4 = self.layer3(x3)
```

In this option, I detach when feeding into each subsequent block

```
    # option 2
    # x2 = self.layer1(x1.detach())
    # x3 = self.layer2(x2.detach())
    # x4 = self.layer3(x3.detach())
```

shared ops which calculate 4 losses and sum them.

```
    x4 = F.relu(self.bn1(x4))
    loss = some_loss([x1, x2, x3, x4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is correct. When you detach a tensor, computation history/graph is lost and gradients won't be propogated to inputs/for computation done before detaching.

This can also be seen by this toy experiment.

```
In [14]: import torch                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [15]: x = torch.rand(10,10).requires_grad_()                                                                                                                                                       

In [16]: y = x**2                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [19]: z = torch.sum(y)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [20]: z.backward()                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [23]: x.grad is not None                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[23]: True
```

Using detach

```
In [26]: x = torch.rand(10,10).requires_grad_()                                                                                                                                                       

In [27]: y = x**2                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [28]: z = torch.sum(y)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [29]: z_ = z.detach()                                                                                                                                                                              

In [30]: z_.backward()  
# this gives error
```

This is because when you call detach, it returns a new tensor with the values copied and information about previous computations is lost.